# why the same font at different web brower have different looks?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY79G.png)
I found that the font 'monospace' have diferent styles at my Chrome and Brave web browser. Can someone tell me why?
I also checked my Microsoft Edge, it has the same style as Brave.

I think they are all based on the chromium, so i dont know why my chrome have a different styles of the 'monospace' And i have checked my extensions, they have nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Please post your index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by different **language settings**.

The left example renders the **NSimSun** font.
The right one shows the NSimSun.

Keep in mind `font-family: monospace` translates to:
"use any available monospaced font - suitable for the current text/encoding"

```css
body{
  font-size:2em;
  font-family:  monospace
}

.consolas{
    font-family: Consolas, monospace
}
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li lang="zh">Chinese (zh): font test<span>你好</span></li>
    <li>Chinese (no lang): font test<span>你好</span></li>
    <li>French: <span lang="fr">Bonjour</span></li>
    <li lang="ja">Japanese: <span lang="ja">今日は</span></li>
    <li lang="ko">Korean: <span lang="ko">안녕하세요</span></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="consolas">
    <li lang="zh">Chinese (zh): font test<span>你好</span></li>
    <li>Chinese (no lang): font test<span>你好</span></li>
    <li>French: <span lang="fr">Bonjour</span></li>
    <li lang="ja">Japanese: <span lang="ja">今日は</span></li>
    <li lang="ko">Korean: <span lang="ko">안녕하세요</span></li>
  </ul>
```

For a consistent font rendering, just add a specific font family name like

```
font-family: Consolas, monospace
```